# How to make a virtual Directory?

Tags: php, directory, virtual

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_do_the_abbreviations_mean_on_an_ultrasound_scan

In above url, it looks like "What_do_the_abbreviations_mean_on_an_ultrasound_scan" is a directory!! but i think its a virtual directory !!

I want to know about this stuff !! how to do these things and what they call ???

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: Do you have a point?

Answer (score 2):

They are most probably using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite the url. A good resource is the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) for mod_rewrite here on StackOverflow.

The rules for mod_rewrite is stored in the .htaccess file, and looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/Q/(.*?)$ answers.php?slug=$1
```

This would rewrite all requests whitch match a url starting with `/Q/` to answers.php, and provide whatever is after (in this case `What_do_the_abbreviations_mean_on_an_ultrasound_scan`) as a GET parameter. This would be accessible in the script as `$_GET['slug']` if they were running PHP.